# Second Order Differential Equations $ay''+by'+cy=0$, without complex numbers

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve the following equation without using Second Order Differential Equations formulas or Power Series:

$$af^{''}(x)+bf^{'}(x)+cf(x)=0$$
where $b^2-4ac<0$.

I know that the soltution is something like this:

$$f(x)=A\sin (qx)+B\cos (qx)$$
In any event, I would like to know how to solve this equation without that well-known formula that we find in any Differential Equations Course. I would like an elementary solution to this equation and without complex numbers.

For instance, if $b^2-4ac>0$ then we can solve it by using something like that: $$(e^{kx}g(x))^{'}=0$$. Can't we do something similar as well?

The second question I want to ask is if I want to solve the equation with Power Series is it correct the following approach:

I prove by induction that $f$ is infinitely derivable and after that I assume:

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$$
I know that not all infinitely derivable can be written in this form, for example:
$e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$.
So it shoul be wrong. Nonetheless, there are several people who provide solutions to this problem by using this fact which for me seems to be blatantly erroneous.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#Second-order_case

Comment: I suppose $a,b,c$ are constants. There is a theorem which says that if $f_1$ and $f_2$ are linearly independent solution the all solutions are linear combinations of these two. The power series method is used to obtain two linearly independent solution.

Comment: Thank you, but I would like an elemenary solution to this.

Comment: What means exactly "elementary"?

Comment: Like the soltution when $b^2-4ac>0$, we would multiply the equation with $e^{kx}$, and then we would have $(e^{kx}g(x))^{'}=0$ and we will obtain $f$

Comment: The answer to "Can't we do something similar" is Yes; it must be in all the DE books. In the simplest case of $f''+f=0$ we just multiply by $f'$ and use MVT to see that $\frac12 (f')^2+\frac12 f^2$ is constant. Etc Etc.

Comment: About the second issue: the method will be OK. You use it, find a solution, then check it really is convergent, then see that the difference between this solution and any solution must be $0$, essentially by using MVT. Exciting functions like $e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$ don't turn up (which is a relief).

Comment: BTW: good question, and one too few people ask themselves.

Comment: ancient mathematician, how do you continue after seeing that $(f^{'})^2+f^2$ is a constant?

Comment: @shangq_tou I have posted that as a partial answer.

Answer (score 2):

@Vercassivelaunos has explained how to reduce the problem to looking at the problem $g''+m^2 g=0$; by replacing $x$ by $mx$ we need only look at the problem $g''+g=0$.

Let us show that there is a unique solution, given that $g(0)=A, g'(0)=B$. Clearly $A\cos x+ B\sin x$ is a solution with these initial conditions, so look at $h(x):=g(x)-A\cos x+ B\sin x$; this satisfies $h''+h=0$, $h(0)=0,h'(0)=0$. We want to show that $h(x)=0$ for all $x$.

Multiplying $h''+h=0$  by $h'$ we see that $h'' h'+h'h=0$ for all $x$. Note that $h''h'+h'h=(\frac12 (h')^2+\frac12 h^2)'$. Therefore, by the Mean Value Theorem,
$$
\frac12 h'(x)^2+\frac12 h(x)^2=(x-0)(\frac12 (h'(\theta x)^2+\frac12 h(\theta x)^2)=0. 
$$
Now a real sum of squares can only be zero if each summand is zero. So we have, as required, $h(x)=0$ for all $x$.

[For those of an applied bent, we are just doing the classical thing of conserving the total energy.]

Answer (score 1):

You *can* make the educated guess that the solution will be of the form $f(x)=e^{kx}g(x)$. Then we get

$$\begin{align}&{~}a[e^{kx}g(x))''+b(e^{kx}g(x))'+ce^{kx}g(x)\\
&=a[e^{kx}g''(x)+2ke^{kx}g'(x)+k^2e^{kx}g(x)]~+~b[e^{kx}g'(x)+ke^{kx}g(x)]~+~ce^{kx}g(x)\\
&=ae^{kx}g''(x)~+~[2ak+b]e^{kx}g'(x)~+~[ak^2+bk+c]e^{kx}g(x)\\
&=0\end{align}$$

Since $e^{kx}$ is never $0$, this reduces to

$$ag''+(2ak+b)g'+(ak^2+bk+c)g=0.$$

We are free to choose $k$ as we wish, because if $e^{kx}g(x)$ solves the ODE, then so does $e^{\tilde kx}e^{(k-\tilde k)x}g(x)$, and we simply get $\tilde g(x)=e^{(k-\tilde k)}g(x)$ as the solution for $g$ instead. So we choose $k$ as simple as possible: such that $2ak+b=0$, that is, $k=-\frac{b}{2a}$. Then the equation reads (after multiplying by $4a$)

$$4a^2g''-(b^2-4ac)g=0.$$

The solution to this, given that $b^2-4ac<0$, is known: it's of the form $g(x)=A\sin(\omega x)+B\cos(\omega x)$, where $\omega:=\sqrt{c-\frac{b^2}{4a}}$.

So in total we get $f(x)=e^{kx}[A\sin(\omega x)+B\cos(\omega x)]$ with $k$ and $\omega$ as specified.